# Mapping a unique network or webdav drive for each user in linux

Tags: debian, networking, login

I am trying to setup a linux machine to map a users network drive on campus when they login.

We have a network drive that can be accessed by //domain/mydrive/

It asks for login info and then will show your folder myusername. It also has webdav if needed http://domain/mydrive/.

What we want is when a user logs in it maps this network share to ~/m/.

If it is not possible to map it on login (due to the username/password needed) it would be ok to setup a script to do such that they could run.

Issues we have been having is that non-root users can not map the drive (we do have access to root if changes need to be made). Other solutions we have tried will only map one users drive. Most of the directions we have seen require us adding to the fstab but adding each users drive to this list is not feasible.